# How to write unit test for global functions where it is calling another global function using gtest/gmock in C++?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have around 10 global functions in file. Need to write unit test cases for each of them. A global function could be called from another global function.

You can consider following three global functions.

```
int bar(int n){
    ..........
    //Could call another global function.
    ..........
}

int foo(int n){
    ..........
    int b = bar(x);
    ..........
}

int hut(int n){
    ..........
    ..........  
    int a = foo(x);
    ..........
    ..........  
    int b = hut(y);
    ..........
    ..........
}
```

In the time of testing hut(), function foo() and bar() should be mocked. Same thing could happens with foo() and bar() too. I am using gtest and gmock. Is it possible to do using gtest and gmock?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Depending on your OS and toolchain, you may be able to do
this with googletest and the linker's help. What are they? Linux/GCC? Windows/VC++...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are in the same file there sadly is no (sane) way to mock those Global Functions. Even if they are not, you would have a hard time doing this (e.g. modifying the original code to `#include` the mock headers instead of the real ones when building the code for unit testing), and it will **not** be pretty, so I'd strongly advise you against it.

While there is a [third party extension](https://github.com/apriorit/gmock-global) to add global mocking support, it only helps in the creation of the mock, but unfortunately not the *"how do I get my functions to call the mock instead"* issue.

They cover this in [this FAQ](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#my-code-calls-a-staticglobal-function--can-i-mock-it) and even provide possible workarounds [in their Blog](https://testing.googleblog.com/2008/06/defeat-static-cling.html) - you can rewrite your code in a way to "get rid" of the static global function and making your code testable.

**In short:** No, there is no good & easy way to mock global functions (especially if they call other globals), you may be better off refactoring the code into something more testable instead.

Comment: Isolator++ is free. https://www.typemock.com/isolatorpp-product-page/